# shopify js buy sdk not working in wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, shopify, shopify-app

I want to use shopify js buy sdk with wordpress. I've downloaded the sdk files and follow the steps as described in the [documentation](http://shopify.github.io/js-buy-sdk/)

```
import Client from 'shopify-buy';

const client = Client.buildClient({
  domain: 'your-shop-name.myshopify.com',
  storefrontAccessToken: 'your-storefront-access-token'
});
```

But It always give an error, which says **import declarations may only appear at top level of a module**.

So I've keep it at the top and add **type="module"** at the script tag. then the error is solved, but javascript code within this script is not working...

So, can anyone tell me what can I deo to solve this problem?

Comment: The JS SDK assumes you are running a Node server somewhere, it sounds like you are just trying to add the SDK as a regular script and expecting it to work. This will not work, as CORS will block any requests made from other public URLS. Not to mention that including the full SDK would also expose your access token, giving anyone full access to your store.

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't using any of the Node or JS package managers then try using the UMD package available on their documentation page:

```
<script src="http://sdks.shopifycdn.com/js-buy-sdk/v1/latest/index.umd.min.js"></script>
```

You can use it like any other js script, it exposes a global window.ShopifyBuy factory.

Then use it like this:

```
const client = window.ShopifyBuy.buildClient({
  domain: 'your-shop-name.myshopify.com',
  storefrontAccessToken: 'your-storefront-access-token'
});
```